# WordPress how to give access to a page only for subscribers

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to give access of the specific page just for my subscriber user role, if someone else with other then subscriber role or non role user want to access to this page redirect them to a custom login page, I tried with below snippet but I think something is wrong with it, can you please help me to fix this

Example : Restrict access to specific pages

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    // Get global post
    global $post;

    // Prevent access to page with ID 1052
    $page_id = 1052;
    if ( is_page() && ( $post->post_parent == $page_id || is_page( $page_id ) ) ) {

        // Set redirect to true by default
        $redirect = true;

        // If logged in do not redirect
        // You can/should place additional checks here based on user roles or user meta
        if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) || !is_user_logged_in()) {
            $redirect = false;
        }

        // Redirect people without access to login page
        if ( $redirect ) {
            wp_redirect( get_site_url().'/custom-url-login' ); exit;
        }


    }

} );
```

Comment: So why do you think "something is wrong with it"? 1- Do you get any errors? 2- Did it behave the way you didn't expect?

Comment: @Ruvee the problem with that code is I am getting too many redirects it is keeping redirect the same (custom-url-login) page

Comment: `is_page()` in your conditional is unnecessary. You only need the other two.

Comment: @jahn The code you provided us in your question doesn't give a clue why such a redirect loop is happening. My wild guess is your .htaccess or there is another redirect elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could refactor your code like this:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'checking_current_user' );

function checking_current_user() 
{

  global $post;

  global $current_user;
  
  $page_id = 1052;

  if ( 
      ( $post->post_parent == $page_id || is_page( $page_id ) )
      &&  
      ( !in_array('subscriber', $current_user->roles) )
     ) 
  {
    wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/custom-url-login') );
    exit;
  }
  
}
```

This answer has been tested and works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do what you asked for?

```
// If user role 'subscriber' & logged in do not redirect
    // You can/should place additional checks here based on user roles or user meta
    if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) && is_user_logged_in()) {
        $redirect = false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the problem is that other user role have also access to page (page_id = 1052) I want just subscriber role have access to this page not other user role

Comment: @jahn Ah ok, i will look into it again

Comment: now it is keeping redirect in same page ( custom-url-login)

Comment: @Jahn Sorry, but I don't understand, what you meant exactly with the last comment.

Comment: when I tried to login with other user role the page (custom-url-login) reloading continuously

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Admin Dashboard > Appearance > Theme File Editor > Theme Functions **functions.php**

Edit code by adding to the bottom:

```
 // Allow subscribers to see Private posts and pages
 $subRole = get_role( 'subscriber' ); 
 $subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
 $subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
```

Then change your chosen Pages / Posts from Public to **Private** visibility:

Pages > All Pages > Page > Quick Edit > Private (check box)

You can do a redirection, replace `siteurl` at the bottom of **functions.php** using:

```
// Redirect to page on login
function loginRedirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && $user->has_cap( 'edit_posts' ) === false ) {
        return get_bloginfo( 'siteurl' );
    }
    return $redirect_to; }

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'loginRedirect', 10, 3 );
```

or URL redirection to the "page only for subscribers" e.g:

https://WordPress.com/wp-login.php?user_id=3&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.com%2Fabout%2F#top

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must need to check user is logged-in or not, If user is not logged-in then you need to redirect user to login page, After to login you need to apply code code then it will work fine.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_current_user' );
function check_current_user(){
 global $post, $current_user;
$page_id = 1052;
if ( is_page() && ( $post->post_parent == $page_id || is_page( $page_id ) ) ) {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      /*==Now check user is subscriber==*/
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $role = $current_user->roles;
      $currentRole = $role[0];
      if($currentRole == "subscriber"){
         $redirect = false;
      }else{
         $redirect = true;
      }
  }else{
     wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/custom-url-login') );
  }
 }
}
```